# Android How change the value of an element of ArrayList<Integer>()?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to change the value of an element of the list.
I have tried this code:

```
List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();

numeros.get(2)=12;
```

But this gives an error. 
Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Use `set()` not `get()`

Comment: Ok, can you give me a example pls?

Comment: For future reference, you should post the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [set(int index, E object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method defined in the ArrayList class.

Answering to your question you just need to do:

```
numbers.set(2, 12);
```

**But**, be careful with this. The index value must be `index < 0 || index >= size()` or you will get your app crashing with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

try `numeros.set(2, 12);` to update ArrayList member

Answer (score 0):

`numeros.get(2)` gives you the value of the list item at index 2, not a reference to it.
You may try using [set (int location, E object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) instead.

That is:`numeros.set (location, newValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

numbers.set(2, 12);

Where `set(int index, E element)`, in your case, `set(int index, Integer element)`
For more info, check the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29)